# Control-m - Job´s in the line command

Tags: control-m

Is there any way to see Control-M Job´s in the line command  ?
Eveyday I use the Control-M Enterprise Manager GUI, but I´m looking for any way to see all jobs in the line command.

Answer (score 1):

Query the DB of Control-M Server:

```
Select * From Cms_Jobdef Where Tasktype = 'C '
```

If you have access to the API you will get the response in JSON format:

```
ctm run jobs:status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the "planning" or "monitoring" tools and then select "View" and then "List" (instead of "Map") then it will list all job in non-graphical mode - so you can see all the commands listed (where applicable).

If you have access to the Control-M Server machine itself then this query on the DB will list all commands (where the command line contains text) -

select SCHEDTAB, JOBNAME, CMDLINE from CMS_JOBDEF where CMDLINE IS NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using version 8 or higher, you can use CTRL+L on EM GUI to view the jobs as a list.

On the header of the list, right click and use the column chooser to choose to display the commands of the jobs.